What's a suitable Chinese name for the Community bot?
The Community♦ user on some localized sites has its name changed.  From what I understand, it's next-to-trivial to implement (as simple as changing a username).  So...
Question: What's a suitable Chinese name for Community♦?
I'm not 100% sure it'd be okay here (the other sites where Community's name has changed are wholly localized, e.g. it's Дух сообщества♦ at Русский язык, but it's still Community♦ on Russian.SE).  However, it'll be easier to discuss whether or not it's possible, if we have a concrete suggestion.
I believe the only restriction is that it has to be 3 or more characters.
Usernames starting with Chinese characters are hard to @-ping, but this is not relevant for a bot.
Relevant meta.SE threads are Rename the Community user on localized sites and Localize the username of the Community user on rus.SE and ja.SO.

I guess; what does "Community" even mean in this instance?

I guess it's named Community because what it does is mostly prompted by the community, e.g., auto-deletion as a result of community voting/closing.

社群 might be an option.
MDBG

社群
  shè​qún​
  community / social grouping


I'm not sure that such an ambiguous name would work in Chinese. Something like 版主 would be much clearer.
I'd even opt for:
堆主
a mash up of "stack" (堆), i.e.: stack overflow & mod (主), i.e.: moderator. Similarly:
栈主
could also work.

I think it needs to be 3 or more characters; maybe we need to combine these (社群版主 (?)).  And I guess we also need to be careful with traditional vs. simplified.

We could maybe add 机 on the end to imply it's a bot？

It seems 社群机器人 might be possible... I'm a bit concerned about traditional/simplified, so maybe "Community 社群" is possible. hmmm  [I guess it'd be good to go with something safe, like "Community 社群".]

for the “community bot”, i would suggest “叩鐘掾”.
in which, “叩鐘” is derived from the book of rites, chapter education (禮記　學記)

善待問者
to skilfully (善) treat (待 —-> 對待) an asker (問者)
如撞鐘
is like (如) striking (撞) a bell (鐘)
叩之以小者・則小鳴
strike it gently, the bell sounds softly
叩之以大者・則大鳴
strike it forcefully, the bell sounds loudly

then, “掾” is assistant to an official.
